# Uploading Image works but doesn't store into Databse

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I am trying to upload a image into my database.

The script works fine and shows no error messages. The script successfully uploads to a directory within my server called 'profilepics' however it fails to update the database with the image information, there are no errors and when I echo out the script everything works fine such as session variables, the image name field etc.

Here is my query:

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET image='$pic' WHERE memberID='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit ("Error in query: $query. ".mysqli_error());

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  {   
//Tells you if its all ok  
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  
}  
else {   //Gives and error if its not  
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";  
}
```

Comment: You are doing an `UPDATE` query. Does that record already exist?

Comment: What do you mean by record? The column image exists however it is empty, will this be a problem? Can I not use a UPDATE where a column is empty? @JustinWood

Comment: use `INSERT` instead.

Comment: When I say record, I mean a row in your database. If you have not previously `INSERT`ed a record into your database, you will not be able to `UPDATE` it.

Comment: I think you should move the update query in the "if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  {" construction and take the url of the file from there.

Comment: Cheers Justin, How would I write that query.... like so? $query = "INSERT INTO members VALUES('$pic') WHERE memberID='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'";       :/

Comment: Thanks @valicu2000 didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` is only used when you have an existing row which you want to, update.

So use `INSERT INTO`, as you're inserting a new row.

Example of an `INSERT INTO QUERY` using your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members(`image`) VALUES ('". $pic . "')";
```

Comment: Well its only an example, how does your column `image` look like, and how does `$pic` look like

Comment: How will this work would it not through an error as were trying to re insert the memberID with it being a PK Unique and Auto Incremented? Sorry if im wrong

Comment: Well you've gotta tweak it yourself to get it to work, i dont know how your database looks like, once again, its only an example.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help everyone, but I found the issue silly me! the query was perfect in case anyone wanted to know, i was being stupid and didn't realize my session is a username and I was checking to see if it matches my memberID -_________________________-

Thanks again